# SQL optimise IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I am trying to optimise the following:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM #SearchResults sr
    WHERE 
        sr.src_data_col1 = @SearchCriteria OR
        sr.src_data_col2 = @SearchCriteria OR
        sr.src_data_col3 = @SearchCriteria
    )
    BEGIN

        SELECT *
        FROM #SearchResults sr
        WHERE 
            sr.src_data_col1 = @SearchCriteria OR
            sr.src_data_col2 = @SearchCriteria OR
            sr.src_data_col3 = @SearchCriteria
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM #SearchResults
    END
```

Is doing 2 `SELECT` statements going to make it slower? or am I not understanding how `EXISTS` works correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, you can save the data into another temporary table:

```
SELECT *
INTO #SearchResults_2
FROM #SearchResults sr
WHERE sr.src_data_col1 = @SearchCriteria OR
      sr.src_data_col2 = @SearchCriteria OR
      sr.src_data_col3 = @SearchCriteria;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #SearchResults_2)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM #SearchResults_2;
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM #SearchResults;
END;
```

Under most circumstances, such an optimization would be unnecessary.  If the search results only have a few tens or hundreds of rows, then it probably is not worth creating another temporary table.  However, you can do timings on your system, with your data, to see if the optimization is worth the effort.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, when inside an `EXISTS` I prefer to do a `SELECT NULL`, so it's evident that I'm not interested in any column in particular. :)

Comment: @Andrew . . . Personally, I abhor `select NULL` in this context.  I find it quite confusing that a `NULL` value in a single column in a single row is counted for `EXISTS`.  It would not be counted in other context such as `COUNT()`.  I regularly use `select 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a quite short way to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT *
FROM #SearchResults sr
WHERE @SearchCriteria IN (sr.src_data_col1, sr.src_data_col2, sr.src_data_col3)
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
        FROM #SearchResults sr
        WHERE @SearchCriteria IN (sr.src_data_col1, sr.src_data_col2, sr.src_data_col3));
```

If the subquery returns nothing, that condition becomes `true` and you get all your results.